# How to show read-only forms?

Tags: forms

i have a long list of labels and texts which are in Read-only mode. Do I need to show them with their type i.e., filled text-field and filled-combo-box.
or just show text?
My main concern is some of the fields are un-filled and empty boxes are confusing.
if i omit them it feels unbalanced as my current form is 2-column layout.

The data generally is in this type inside a card.

[image]

Comment: If you show a sample or a mockup of your layout, will help you get better answers

Comment: A more described context would probably help to get concise answers :)

Comment: check the edited question

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are these fields something the user has previously filled? If not,it does not make much sense to have it as a read only form.

Coming to the question, I'd have to say using muted colours for the fields without content and optionally using NA or Nil as placeholders for them would make sense. Arranging these in a multi column layout in a card would also be great in certain cases. Again, a context to your question will help a lot.

Comment: Yeah these are previously filled by a user and it is shown to him and his manager.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the usecase and your priorities.

If you want to give awesome look & feel to your application and a structured navigation, I belive that you should not use input fields to show information. In my opinion you should use plain text as headings and records. For example:

**First name** : John Doe

With this approach if you have edit feature on the same page then it should open all the fields in their respective input fields and a submit button in a different page.

In the scenario for edit if you want to make things quicker for the user you can go ahead with the read-only form and on the click of edit you can unlock all the fields. 
Hope this will help.

Comment: Yeah, even visuals are given great importance by my client. actually he is only bothered only abt visuals.  :P